# How to enable bluetooth on a HP ProBook 430 with a Realtek 8723BE

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, hp, realtek

The built in drivers from Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 14 are not able to support bluetooth functionality of my RTL8723BE chip. I used to install the drivers from this two unofficial repos:

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
https://github.com/troy-tan/driver_store/raw/master/bluetooth/8723BE/

Those drivers temporary make bt work but very unstable and they are overwritten with Ubuntu updates - so this is not a solution to reinstall unstable drivers day by day.

Is there a way to get this BT chip work stable and consistant in ubuntu 14, the same way as under windows?

Comment: You still need to use lwfinger's rtlwifi_new but for bluetooth use https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/tree/troy   It is slowly getting integrated into a upstream kernel, so you will still need to reinstall after a kernel update

Comment: Thanks to all suggestions made, however the problem is not solved yet! The method suggested by pilot6 did not work is 2 such HP Probook 430 g2. The possibility of any hardware problem is most improbable, as bluetooth work in both units in Windows 8.1. Thanks to all anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The bluetooth driver is in ppa now

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```

No need to re-install it after kernel upgrades any more.